# National Flags and their Movies

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, movies, flags

This puzzle is divided into four parts. In each part, certain national flags are linked to certain movies.

- ***Which national flag replaces the question mark in part 2?***
- ***Which movie replaces the question mark in part 2?***

---

**Part 1**

[image]

---

**Part 2**

[image]

---

**Part 3**

[image]

---

**Part 4**

[image]

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The missing flag and movie poster are those of:

> **Sweden** and ***The Hurt Locker***.

Because this puzzle is a tribute to:

> the career of tennis legend **[Roger Federer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Federer#Career_statistics)**, who in the last 24 hours [announced his upcoming retirement](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/tennis/62911876) from the sport.

The important fact to note is that:

> during his career, Federer won **20 Grand Slam titles** - the Grand Slams being the Australian Open, French Open, Wimbledon, and the US Open. Here in this puzzle we are being asked to find a *twentieth* flag-and-film combo - a perfect correspondence.

So what do the flags and movie posters represent?

> First note that each of these movies won the [Academy Award for Best Picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Award_for_Best_Picture). If we consider the **year** that each of these movies won, then we find that *in that year* Federer beat **an opponent of the nationality indicated by the flag** in the final of a Grand Slam tournament.
>
>  With the four different 'Parts' each representing a different Grand Slam tournament (in the order that they are usually hosted in a calendar year), we can interpret Parts 1, 3 and 4 as follows:
>
>  **Part 1: Federer's 6 Australian Open wins**
>  *Million Dollar Baby* & Russia = 2004 vs Marat Safin
>  *The Departed* & Cyprus = 2006 vs Marcos Baghdatis
>  *No Country for Old Men* & Chile = 2007 vs Fernando González
>  *The King's Speech* & UK = 2010 vs Andy Murray
>  *The Shape of Water* & Spain = 2017 vs Rafael Nadal
>  *Green Book* & Croatia = 2018 vs Marin Čilić
>
>  **Part 3: Federer's 8 Wimbledon wins**
>  *LotR: Return of the King* & Australia = 2003 vs Mark Philippoussis
>  *Million Dollar Baby* & USA = 2004 vs Andy Roddick
>  *Crash* & USA = 2005 vs Andy Roddick
>  *The Departed* & Spain = 2006 vs Rafael Nadal
>  *No Country for Old Men* & Spain = 2007 vs Rafael Nadal
>  *The Hurt Locker* & USA = 2009 vs Andy Roddick
>  *Argo* & UK = 2012 vs Andy Murray
>  *The Shape of Water* & Croatia = 2017 vs Marin Čilić
>
>  **Part 4: Federer's 5 US Open wins**
>  *Million Dollar Baby* & Australia = 2004 vs Lleyton Hewitt
>  *Crash* & USA = 2005 vs Andre Agassi
>  *The Departed* & USA = 2006 vs Andy Roddick
>  *No Country for Old Men* & Serbia = 2007 vs Novak Djokovic
>  *Slumdog Millionaire* & UK = 2008 vs Andy Murray

Which means our missing one must represent:

> **Part 2: Federer's 1 French Open win**
>  *The Hurt Locker* & Sweden = 2009 vs Robin Söderling

Comment: Always a joy to read your comprehensive explanation!